# passing variable in javascript function using django template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

here I am passing {{id}} to hide_show(...) javascript function

```
{% for stock in part_temp.part_stock_set.all %}
    {% with id="list"|concatenate:stock.id %}
    <div id="{{ id }}">
    {{ stock.entry_date}}
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="hide_show({{ id }})">edit</button>
    <br>
        {{ id }}
```

here above the {% endwith %} {{ id }} is displaying correctly but the hide_show function in not called but it is called when just {{ stock.id }} is passed to it.
the concatenate filter just concatenates and returns a string.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function hide_show(temp) {
        document.getElementById(temp).style.display='none';
        window.alert(temp);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be with the quotes. if {{ id }} returns a string, then you don't have to put quotes here

```
<div id="{{ id }}">
```

Simply replace it with:

```
<div id={{ id }}>
```

If id is an integer or if the above doesn't work, then you have to put quotes here as well as in the argument while calling the hide_show function.

Comment: it's not an integer though single quotes in arguments while calling the javascript function worked